# How to get a token claim value and inject on a dbcontext service

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I Have a DbContext where i need a CompanyId to make a global query, like multi tenant.

```
    public void SetGlobalQuery<T>(ModelBuilder builder) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        builder.Entity<T>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.CompanyId == _companyId);
    }
```

The CompanyId is added to a token claim, how i'm can get the claim value and inject on the DbContext?

```
    services.AddScoped(provider => {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        var options = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbDatabase")).Options;
        var companyId = 1;
        return new DocContext(options, companyId);
    });
```

Comment: How would you get a claim value when the application starts? There's nobody around yet to provide an authorization token. Moreover, that would only allow one tenant for the whole application. You should inject "something" that acquires the token at runtime, for example the `ITenantProvider` in [this blog](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/09/defensive-database-context/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the current user through the IHttpContextAccessor service and then search for the CompanyId claim:

```
//using System.Security.Claims;

services.AddScoped(provider => {
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
    var options = optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbDatabase")).Options;

    var user = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User;
    int? companyId = int.TryParse(user.FindFirstValue("CompanyId"), out var companyId) ? companyId : (int?)null;

    return new DocContext(options, companyId);
});
```

Please note, CompanyId is a nullable int. If the user isn't authenticated then CompanyId is null.

Side note: If you are using Identity then IHttpContextAccessor is injected for you. Otherwise you'll have to do that yourself.